# How many questions there are in 70-667 exam and how long do I have?

Tags: certification

How many questions there are in 70-667 exam and how long do I have? I have been prepared for this test + i have few years in SP admin and config (plus some development with powershell and vs c#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly but there was 47/48 questions for me. You have 2 hours + 45 mn if you don't pass the exam in your native language.

Good luck